# Scala def in an object - naming convention upper case camel case?

Tags: scala, naming-conventions

Given the conventions here: http://docs.scala-lang.org/style/naming-conventions.html

> Blockquote
>   Constant names should be in upper camel case. That is, if the member is final, immutable and it belongs to a package object or an object, it may be considered a constant (similar to Java’s static final members)

Does that mean that a def should fall in that category too? Especially if functionally pure. For example a Parse method:

```
object Parser{def Parse(string: String): AnyRef = ??? }
```

Comment: I recommend you take the "elements of Scala `object`s are like Java statics" with a grain of salt. Likewise for the "Scala `object`s are singletons." They're more complicated than that and if you think of them only in that way, you're likely to encounter situations where the behavior of your code puzzles you. You might even hypothesize that the compiler has a bug...

Comment: Modulo grains of salt, I don't know why the next sentence in the guide isn't persuasive: "Method, Value and variable names should be in lower camel case." That is in no way ambiguous.

Answer (score 4):

No, it shouldn't.

That explanation is mostly a simplification of the concept of a stable value. A stable value is something that you can trust to always have the same value, and it is how Scala introduces dependent types (aka, in Scala, as path-dependent types).

There are a number of rules for what is a stable value, which is why a simpler explanation is resorted to in the style guide. One specific rule is that it *has to be* a `val` -- `var` and `def` are not acceptable. A `var` is not acceptable because the value can change at any time, and a `def` is not acceptable because it may return different values each time it is called (even if it receives no parameters).

Also related to this is the fact that you can override a `def` with a `val`, but not vice versa.

So only `val` qualifies as constants.

Also of interest, Scala optimizes final val declarations when you do not declare a type, like this:

```
object Constants {
  final val Zero = 0
}
```

That will cause Scala to replace instances of `Zero` with `0`. In fact, if you recompile `Constant` changing the value of `Zero` from `0` to something else, any code making reference to `Constants.Zero` that has been compiled before will still use `0`.

If, on the other hand, you had declared it as `final val Zero: Int = 0`, that would not happen.

Answer (score 0):

No.  Method names should start with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Thanks I thought so but the category actually says "Constants, Values, Variable and Methods" where it describes the convention.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Refering to the naming conventions:

> Textual (alphabetic) names for methods should be in the camelCase
>   style with the first letter lower-case:

```
def myFairMethod = ...
```

Upper case names are meant for constants.

> Method, Value and variable names should be in lower camel case:

```
val myValue = ...
def myMethod = ...
var myVariable
```

So in your case it'll be:

```
object Parser {
 def parse(string: String): AnyRef = ???  
}
```